# Android root HTC ONE M7 infinite boot

Tags: rooting, root-access, htc, htc-one

I have HTC ONE M7 and I tried to root it . I did everything but it seems I did something wrong. It stuck at the recovery thing when I reboot it again and again it opens the recovery page. what should I do ?

Comment: can you elaborate more over what you did? what guide did you follow (if you did). did you get any errors when flashing etc..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with what you used to root, but I know the HTC One M7 has problems reading the ISO boot file provided depending on the version of the phone. However I found very reliable resources you may be able to use...
Read everything carefully from the links...
First try to fix the recovery with [HBOOT](http://htconeroot.com/cwmtwrp-recoveries/)

Next I would try to do a factory recovery and then follow one of these methods [Flashify](http://htconeroot.com/cwmtwrp-recoveries/) or [FromXDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2618524) XDAforum
If not, a hard reset and hopefully the image files are available online. I think HTC has tons of options so don't panic, just be patient... You will get it...

Comment: http://htconeroot.com/htc-one-root/how-to-root-htc-one-windowsmaclinux/

Comment: i did like that but used different supersu

Comment: Can you get to HBOOT by holding the volume down button?

Comment: yes i can  get to there

Comment: you still here mr nixxbb ?

Comment: Rev ised answer to the best of my ability to help with the time I have now. I will check back later to see how it went. Take your time and it will be fine.

Comment: Forgot about this link, has images and easy to understand http://highonandroid.com/android-apps/how-to-flash-img-files-on-rooted-android-with-flashify-app-root-apps/